# Require User to be Logged in to Download ZIP Files

Tags: asp.net, authentication, file-type

Is it possible to require the user be authenticated (logged in) when downloading ZIP files from my site? Note that I don't have direct control of IIS7. (I'm on a shared hosting account.)

I can't simply alter the access for a particular directory because many directories are involved and most contain other files that can be accessed freely.

I've Googled this a bit and found similar questions. But I've been unable to find this exact question.

**EDIT:** *This is specifically a programming question (even if the answer is that it can't be accomplished via programming). Also, it asks a very specific question. (Apparently, a couple of people were confused on these points.)*

Comment: If you don't own the server and if you don't own .ZIP association, there's nothing you can do. If .ZIP HTTP requests are handled directly by IIS, ASP.NET won't even see the .ZIP HTTP request coming in.

Comment: You can have an ASPX stream the ZIP file to the client and not disclose th direct URL of the file.

Comment: @Simon: The point is that I need to "own the ZIP association". You can map ZIP files to be handled by ASP.NET. What's more, with IIS7, you can do this in your web.config without changing any IIS settings. I've been reading about this for over an hour now. It looks like writing an HTTP handler for ZIP files is not hard to do. The issue giving me the most trouble is that the handler must be in a separate assembly, which would make it harder to test if the current user is authenticated.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, there are a few techniques along the lines of what you suggest. But I'd prefer to avoid them. I should be able to have a regular link to ZIP files, and then have an HTTP handler to intercept those requests. That would be much better for my purposes.

Comment: @Jon to associate an extension to an HTTP handler, you *will* need to control the IIS settings (if it's not 7+ or it's in classic mode). If you *can* change that in IIS, it's easy. Otherwise, it's * theoretically* not possible.

Comment: @Mehrdad: As I mentioned in my OP, this is on IIS7. I've also just learned that User.IsAuthenticated is part of the HttpContext passed to the HTTP handler proc. I don't understand exactly where that is set, but it seems like this is very possible. I'll try that as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I resolved this:

I created a custom HttpHandler for ZIP files. What's really cool with IIS7 is that you can map a file to your handler in the new `<httpHandlers>` section of the web.config file.

The HttpHandler object receives an `HttpContext` object, which includes `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` already filled out for me. I simply pass along the requested file if the user is authenticated, or redirect them to my login page if not.

With older versions of IIS and ASP.NET, it would be necessary to tweak IIS to map ZIP files to ASP.NET. However, IIS and ASP.NET are merging somewhat, making tasks like this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use forms authentication? You could then simply check for a valid auth cookie.

Comment: I am using forms authentication. But that's of no value here.

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but can't you check if the file being accessed has a .zip extension and that there is a valid user accessing the file?

Comment: Where do I perform this check? ZIP files are not normally handled by IIS and so ASP.NET gets no event when a file of this type is being downloaded.

Comment: one way i can think of is to have all download links pass through a sort of proxy page that takes a query string for the path to the file ex: proxypage.aspx?path=thezipfile.zip. On the proxy page check if the file is a zip and there is a valid user, if both conditions are met direct the user to the downloaded file else deny access.

Comment: A far better way (more efficient and use less server resources) would be to have ZIP files mapped to ASP.NET. I could even write code in the Begin_Request in Global.asax to check if the user is logged in and redirect them to the login page if not.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, my solution was to create a controller to handle the downloads, and apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to that controller so, with a route like:

```
downloads/get/{filename}
```

and a controller action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string fileName)
{
    // should pull this path from web.config or a database...
    string downloadFolder=@"c:\inetpub\virt\downloads\";

    // FileResult() renders the binary content of the specified file back to the browser.
    return(new FileResult(Server.MapPath(downloadFolder+fileName), " application/zip"));
}
```

If you're using webforms, there are a couple of different ways to handle it using either an ASPX or ASHX. But, they all come down to the same idea:

1. Parse the url to get the download file name.
2. Find and load the file contents from disk
3. Set the `content-disposition` header in the response to tell the browser what the filename should be
4. `Response.BinaryWrite()` the binary data back to the browser.

[Here's an OLD example article using an ASHX](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/08/27/25568.aspx).

This should fix your problem: since the requests are going through ASP, and not just direct to the ZIP or other files, the requests have to pass through whatever authentication system you're using. (Forms authentication works fine and *does* solve this problem.)

**Update**

[Here's a nice link on MSDN that works in webforms.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654)

Comment: We might be talking about different things. That last article shows how to use an ASPX page as a proxy for a binary download. That's something I'd prefer to avoid. I know I can do this by simply doing a post back and then redirecting to the ZIP file if the user is logged in. But my preference is to trap the request that is made using a "normal" link. For example, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815152 seems close but I'm not sure if that technique will work for me. I'll try it but have to better understand a couple of things first.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest contacting your hosting provider.  Many shared hosting providers give you access to your .htaccess file or some means of securing your site.  This would be different from provider to provider.

Comment: I'm really looking for an ASP.NET solution. I will likely move the site at some point and prefer not to have to go in and make whatever changes are needed again. If this is absolutely impossible in ASP.NET, then I'll review other options.

Comment: Maybe this will help:  http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/07/30/authentication-and-session.aspx  Try using an authenticated session.

Comment: Thanks jmort253 but that doesn't seem to address my issue. The problem is not how to determine if the user is logged in from ASP.NET code. My problem is how to have my code notified in the first place when a regular request is made for a file not typically handled by IIS.